# Java- Check palindrome

Tags: java, palindrome

Could someone please point out the mistake in my program?

The output is always: "it is not a palindrome"

```
String newstr="";
for(int j=length-1;j>0;j--)
{
    char m=str.charAt(j);
    newstr=newstr+m;
}
if(newstr.equals(str) )
    System.out.println("it is a palindrome");
else
    System.out.println("it is not a palindrome");
```

thanks in advance:)

Comment: Please don't edit your question to silently incorporate all fixes given in the answers. This makes it impossible to see what was actually asked. Also -- your updated code should work, so there is no more question to answer.

Comment: @creinig The updated code fails, see [Shah's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16690648/2040040)

Comment: Sorry,and no,it still doesn't work.

Comment: @johnchen902: Ah right, missed that one. So only half of my comment still stands :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, use `String.equals()` to compare Strings instead of `==`.

```
if(newstr.equals(str))
```

Also, string index start with 0, so you need:

```
for(int j=length-1;j>=0;j--)
```

Both fixes should work.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(newstr==str)
```

should probably be

```
if ( newstr.equals( str ) )
```

And do read up on object comparison. You're effectively comparing two pointers, not the string contents.

Of course, with Java 5 and onwards you could just do

```
new StringBuilder( str ).reverse().toString().equals( str );
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

index of array starts from 0. I guess you should use

```
for(int j=length-1;j>=0;j--)
```

instead of

```
for(int j=length-1;j>0;j--)
```

Answer (score 1):

== operator check whether both the reference point to the same object or not.
.equals() method will actually check the content of the Strings.

So your code must be

```
    if(newstr.equals(str))
    System.out.println("it is a palindrome");
    else
    System.out.println("it is not a palindrome");
```

Answer (score 0):

`==`tests for reference equality.

`.equals()` tests for value equality.

Consequently, if you actually want to test whether two strings have the same value you should use `.equals()` (except in a few situations where you can guarantee that two strings with the same value will be represented by the same object

This will be the final code. read  about [string comparison in java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/2179864)

```
  String newstr="";

   for(int j=length-1;j>0;j--)
   {
       char m=str.charAt(j);
       newstr=newstr+m;
    }
    if(newstr.equals( str ) )
    System.out.println("it is a palindrome");
    else
    System.out.println("it is not a palindrome");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isPaliandrome(String str) {
        StringBuilder lettersBuff = new StringBuilder(str);
        String str_inverse = lettersBuff.reverse().toString();
        char[] charArrayInverse = str_inverse.toCharArray();
        boolean isPaliandrome = false;
        String caracInverseConverted = new String(charArrayInverse);
        if (str.equals(caracInverseConverted)) {
            isPaliandrome = true;
        }
        return isPaliandrome;
    }
```